# How customize the installation dialog of WIX?

Tags: installation, wix

How can I customize the text in WIX installation dialog.

The requirement is to have dialog while installing like below:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Cotoso ABC Product                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                 |
|     Please wait while the XXXX version of ABC is configured     |
|                                                                 |
|                                                                 |
|                                                 Cancel          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The title bar has "Cotoso ABC Product" which is the company and product name.
The dialog content is int format of "Please wait while {XXXX version} of {Product Name} is configured".

How to accomplish this in WIX?

Answer (score 2):

[You can change the text of the progress bar dialog](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_progresstext.htm), and you can change the title.
Why add a popup?

Comment: Thanks. There is no "add popup". What I mean is after the MSI is launched, there is only one dialog showing the progress. In this case, does ProgressText apply?

Comment: The ProgressText will be shown in Progress Dialog, you can disable all other dialogs and jump directly to the progress.  
If you don't want any progress to be shown (which is bad UX IMHO) you will need to create a new dialog, at that case take a look at WixEdit.

Answer (score 0):

Including the default progress/error messages will probably accomplish what you require (this stumped me for ages, as it's not very obviously [placed in the documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/WixUI_localization.htm)). Just add:

```
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
```

As for the title bar, I think this just defaults to the Product/@Name attribute.